# Adding colour to random blocks

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, random, block

I am experimenting at the moment with one line in the console displaying a set of 10 randomly generated blocks, each block assigned a separate colour. Here is what I have so far:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim rdm As New Random()
        Dim index As Integer
        Dim block(3) As String
        block(0) = "#"
        block(1) = "@"
        block(2) = "."
        block(3) = "~"
        For index = 1 To 10
            Console.Write(block(rdm.Next(1, 4)))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

I want to assign each of the characters a colour so for example the "#" will be green when displayed, and the "~" will be blue. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring your `blocks` array as `String`, declare it as your own custom type that has a `Char` or `String` property for the text and a `ConsoleColor` property for the colour.  You use your random number as an index into the array as normal, get the colour value and assign it to the `ForegroundColor` property of the `Console` class, then write out the text.